# SVG position different in WebKit and Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, webkit

I'm working on a site redesign and am using SVGs to render some of the graphics in the design. For some reason, the SVG is being shifted down in WebKit browser windows by about 31px as compared to Firefox. Screen capture:
[image: svg screen capture]

Here is the code:

```
 <svg version="1.1" id="shape1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" x="2" y="2" viewBox="-2 0 1002 704" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="min-width:980px; max-width: 1800px;">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad">
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#ff7405" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#f89512" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="shadow1" y="-1%" x="-1%" width="110%" height="150%">
        <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" dx="-2" dy="4" result="offset" />
        <feGaussianBlur in="offset" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" />
        <feColorMatrix in="blur" result="shadow" type="matrix"
          values="0 0 0 0 0
                  0 0 0 0 0 
                  0 0 0 0 0 
                  0 0 0 .6 0"/>
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="shadow" />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
</defs>
<!-- MAIN BOX -->
<path class="wrap" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" style="fill: url(#gradient1); filter: url(#shadow1);" d="M32.3 0.3L935 82.8c34.3 4.2 38.7 28.9 34.1 59.2l-56.7 398.3c-6.4 23.2-29.8 32.9-66.4 34.8L95.4 643.3c-20.2 0-38.7-17.3-41.4-38.5L0.6 38.9C-2 17.6 12.1 0.3 32.3 0.3z"/>
<!-- STROKE -->
<path fill="none" class="wrap-stroke" stroke="#FFEB00" transform="translate(-42,-28)" d="M84.9,37.3l883.1,80c33.6,4.1,37.9,28.1,33.4,57.4l-55.5,386.5c-6.3,22.5-29.1,31.9-64.9,33.8l-734.3,66.2c-19.7,0-37.9-16.7-40.5-37.4L53.9,74.7C51.3,54.1,65.2,37.3,84.9,37.3z"/>

<!-- CONTACT BOX -->
    <svg x="290" y="490">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFC80C" style="stroke: #F26222; stroke-width: 3px;" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M107.7,68.1l456.9-19.3 c9.1,0,16.5,7.9,16.5,17.5l-8.2,75.4c0,9.7-7.4,17.5-16.5,17.5L116,143.5c-9.1,0-16.5-7.9-16.5-17.5l-8.2-40.3 C91.3,75.9,98.6,68.1,107.7,68.1z"/>
    </svg>
 <!-- NAV BOX -->   
    <svg y="-40" x="230">
        <linearGradient id="gradient2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad">
            <stop  offset="5%" style="stop-color:#F68A1F"/>
            <stop  offset="95%" style="stop-color:#F99F1B"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:url(#gradient2);stroke:#FFC80C;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;" d="M69.2,90.5l580.3-4.8c7.7,0,11.5,1.9,9.8,8.8l-6.7,29c-2.1,5.5-6.2,7.1-13.9,7.1l-564.2-9.4c-5.6,0-7.7-1.8-9.5-7.1l-3.8-13.5 C59.1,92.9,61.4,90.9,69.2,90.5z"/>
    </svg>
</svg>
</svg>
```

When I look at this is web inspector, I see nothing that would be making the SVG dropdown like this. Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the 'error' (http://jsfiddle.net/P97PL/). It suggests to me that it's not the SVG..it's the elements around it. Do you have a link?

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, it displays differently in Firefox and Chrome (in Chrome the SVG is being pushed down). Here is a link to the page in development: http://dev.writebrainmedia.com/HTML-new/

Comment: It's fine in my Chrome...and Safari(5). So which is the issue. Firefox or Webkit. You do know you have 20px margin on the wrapper and 12px padding on the body...don't you.?

Comment: I'd like it to display as it does in Firefox. Yes, I know I have a total of 32px of space at the top. In WebKit browsers, it is adding an extra 16px of space above the svg and pushing it down. If it looks identical to you in Webkit vs. Firefox I'd guess your old versions of Webkit browsers are the cause.

Comment: To me, the part that looks most suspect is the mix of `width` attribute and `max-width` inline CSS. WebKit and Blink are generally awful at sizing and rendering SVG, so I'd take charge of it and either declare explicit widths/heights, or only provide the `viewBox` and put it in a well-defined box on your HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the preserveAspectRatio setting I had in the SVG. I had it set to: `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` which made the elements in the SVG render in the middle of the viewBox. From MDN:

> **xMidYMin** - Force uniform scaling.
>   Align the midpoint X value of the element's viewBox with the midpoint X value of the viewport.
>   Align the  of the element's viewBox with the smallest Y value of the viewport.

Changing this setting to xMinyMin made the elements in the SVG render at the top and left of the viewBox.

From MDN:

> **xMinYMin** - Force uniform scaling.
>   Align the  of the element's viewBox with the smallest X value of the viewport.
>   Align the  of the element's viewBox with the smallest Y value of the viewport.

[preserveAspectRatio on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)